# Linux split access and DNAT

Tags: linux, routing

I have a Linux box with two WAN interfaces ($IF1, $IF2) and one LAN interface ($IF3) set up according to http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html.

From the Internet I can ping both $IP1 and $IP2, so split access is set up correctly I think.

I'm also using masquerading and dnat for the local network, as follows ($local_addr is an other server in the local network):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $IF1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $IF2 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $IF1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $local_addr:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $IF2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $local_addr:80
```

The DNAT works only on the WAN interface to which the default route points.

Is there any way I can make DNAT work for both WAN interfaces no matter what interface is used for the default route?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can

```
# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s $local_addr -m conntrack --ctorigdst $IF1 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s $local_addr -m conntrack --ctorigdst $IF2 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2

# ip ru add fwmark 0x1 lookup ISP1 prio 1000
# ip ru add fwmark 0x2 lookup ISP2 prio 2000
```

And don't forget to disable reverse path filtering

```
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
```